# How to get cache file name in Arabic language using cakephp framwork

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.3

i am new in cakephp and i am developing a website in arabic language, and i used a slug in arabic characters but my problem is that the cache file name show characters like Ù«, ØÃ, Ã¬, Ã¹, Ã in place of normal characters.

example :
post_Ù…Ù†-Ù†Ø­Ù†       (the slug is: من-نحن)

post_Ù¬Ù…Š-ÙˆÙ…Ø¯ØÙØ¹-ÙƒÙ…Ø±ÙˆÙŠ-ÙÙŠ-ØªØØ±ÙØ§Øª-Ø§Ø§Ø

so how to do to get a cache file name like that :

post_من-نحن instead of post_Ù…Ù†-Ù†Ø­Ù†

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is a PHP problem, the filesystem API (just like so many other) simply doesn't support unicode, so you'll end up with the ANSI representation of your string.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46990
https://www.google.com/search?q=php+bugs+unicode+filesystem+support&hl=en

You might be able to get it working using the COM extension, however that would require OS specific code, and if it works at all it would also require changes to the CakePHP core, or you would have to use your own caching mechanism, so it's probably easier to simply live with it, and wait for the legendary PHP6 with its full unicode support ‹’’›(Ͼ˳Ͽ)‹’’›